# Is it good to use tables in HTML 5?

Tags: html

I need to display post and related data in column-wise grid and certainly require `table` for those as aligning `div`s in single line, using `float`s is a time consuming thing!

Will appreciate your reviews on Do's and Don't for Tables in HTML5!

Comment: If the data is tabular, use tables; if the content of the table is presentational, don't use tables.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: All latest and forthcoming browsers!
I think it is obsolete as of HTML5?

Comment: @Cruze So, not IE9? In that case, consider CSS Flexbox.

Comment: Will surely take a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simple rule - *Use tables for tabular data, use other elements for presentation(designing layouts using css) like `div`, `section`, `aside`, `nav` etc . which provides meaning to the content they hold rather than using `table` for everything*

The fact is, developers used tables in 90s for drafting their layouts, but now, new CSS3 spec is amazing, it gives you so much hold on designing layouts like [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), `column-count`, behavior of the box model can be altered by using `box-sizing` property, responsive designs are getting better and better using `@media` queries, [`grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)s etc., which you cannot achieve with `table` element... and hence, `table` is only used for storing tabular data.

I've seen many developers having an impression that `table` should be *completely ignored*, and instead they use a whole lot of `div` with 100 lines of CSS, applying `display: table;` `table-cell` `table-row` properties just to get a single table straight.

*So even in HTML5 it is COMPLETELY OK if you use tables for **tabular data***.

---

[From W3 Org : (v4.01)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1)

> Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout
>   document content as this may present problems when rendering to
>   non-visual media. Additionally, when used with graphics, these tables
>   may force users to scroll horizontally to view a table designed on a
>   system with a larger display. To minimize these problems, authors
>   should use [style sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html) to control layout rather than tables.

---

[From (HTML 5)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element)

> Tables should not be used as layout aids. Historically, many Web
>   authors have tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout
>   making it difficult to extract tabular data from such documents. In
>   particular, users of accessibility tools, like screen readers, are
>   likely to find it very difficult to navigate pages with tables used
>   for layout. If a table is to be used for layout it must be marked with
>   the attribute `role="presentation"` for a user agent to properly
>   represent the table to an assistive technology and to properly convey
>   the intent of the author to tools that wish to extract tabular data
>   from the document.
>
> *There are a variety of alternatives to using HTML tables for layout,
>   primarily using CSS positioning and the CSS table model. [[CSS]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsCSS)*

Comment: will tables be supported in future?

Comment: @Cruze Of course they will be supported in the future. Tables are an important part of HTML.

Comment: The question is closed as 'opinion based', but I think some opinions are too good to not follow! It's like saying `Ways to code clean, is purely opinion based, so don't ask for directions!`

Answer (score 6):

According to the specifications, [`<table>`](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/table) represents data with more than one dimension and "must not be used as layout aids."

If you need to display tabular data with more than one dimension, then you should definitely use a table.  If you just need columns, don't.  There are many CSS frameworks out there like bootstrap that can simplify the styles you need to build a grid.

Comment: It's one of the points where WHATWG and W3C versions of the spec contradict each other. The WHATWG spec, yes, totally [prohibits](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) using tables for layout and calls this practice 'non-conforming'. On the other hand, [the W3C version](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) just suggests that 'Tables *should not* be used as layout aids' and clarifies that 'If a table is to be used for layout it must be marked with the attribute `role="presentation"`'.