# Rearrange a table based on classes with javascript for screen size changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently my table html layout looks like this with `<tr>` and `<td>` obviously being used

```
[text1]  [image1] 
[image2] [text2] 
[text3]  [image3]
[image4] [text4]
```

When it reaches <640px it looks like

```
[text1]
[image1]
[image2]
[text2]
[text3]
[image3]
[image4]
[text4]
```

Although i want

```
[text1]
[image1]
[text2]
[image2]
[text3]
[image3]
[text4]
[image4]
```

etc.
Is this possible with CSS or javascript?

```
<table class="overview">
        <tr class="box one fadeInBlock">
            <td>
                <div class="homeInfo2">
                    {{ page.securityText|richtext }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="homeIm1 responsiveness">
                    Secuirty image
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="box two fadeInBlock">
            <td>
                <div class="homeIm2 responsiveness">
                    Fire image
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="homeInfo3">
                    {{ page.fireText|richtext }}
                </div>
            </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: So you want to hide 2nd column?

Comment: Sorry I changed it for no ambiguity

Comment: Also you shouldn't use tables for layout

Comment: @Pete I got told somewhere else i should hmmm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html - on top of the arguments in the question, you also have accessibility concerns.  Also the html spec actually says not to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503456/is-it-good-to-use-tables-in-html-5

Comment: Well thats fair enough. Just change those to 50% and 100% divs then?

Comment: I would use flex: https://jsfiddle.net/rafp3wh0/1/

Comment: Aww thats brill! Thank you! Reading more into it doesnt make sense why theyre still a thing

Comment: They should still be used for tabular data

Comment: Ah I suppose. Should give a warning or something for images.  Cheers!